# Test sessionStorage with Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, session-storage

I'm writing Java based selenium-webdriver tests. The app that I'm testing sets certain values in storageSession e.g. `sessionStorage.setItem("demo", "test")`, how can I check and assert the value of the stored variable `demo` inside my test

Comment: Is that stored in a cookie? if so then u can get that cookie and then from cookie u can get that variable

Comment: thanks, but nope its not inside the cookie, rather stored within a browser's sessionStorage

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found a great utility class https://gist.github.com/roydekleijn/5073579

```
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class LocalStorage {
  private JavascriptExecutor js;

  public LocalStorage(WebDriver webDriver) {
    this.js = (JavascriptExecutor) webDriver;
  }

  public void removeItemFromLocalStorage(String item) {
    js.executeScript(String.format(
        "window.localStorage.removeItem('%s');", item));
  }

  public boolean isItemPresentInLocalStorage(String item) {
    return !(js.executeScript(String.format(
        "return window.localStorage.getItem('%s');", item)) == null);
  }

  public String getItemFromLocalStorage(String key) {
    return (String) js.executeScript(String.format(
        "return window.localStorage.getItem('%s');", key));
  }

  public String getKeyFromLocalStorage(int key) {
    return (String) js.executeScript(String.format(
        "return window.localStorage.key('%s');", key));
  }

  public Long getLocalStorageLength() {
    return (Long) js.executeScript("return window.localStorage.length;");
  }

  public void setItemInLocalStorage(String item, String value) {
    js.executeScript(String.format(
        "window.localStorage.setItem('%s','%s');", item, value));
  }

  public void clearLocalStorage() {
    js.executeScript(String.format("window.localStorage.clear();"));
  }
}
```

thanks Roy

Comment: Python please. I am looking to access the Session Storage and return some files. Help!

Comment: Thank you very much. This really helped me pass through a difficult situation. I was trying to get items from local storage, this method worked for me.

Comment: This is great for local storage but it's missing the equivalent for session storage.

Comment: This is the one for session storage  ```public String getItemFromSessionStorage(String key) {
        return (String) js.executeScript(String.format(
                "return sessionStorage.getItem('%s');", key));
    }```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the answer from [@learnAndImprove](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27566122/6654475) which shows how to retrieve the local storage info, here is the piece we can add to that class to get the session storage.

```
public String getItemFromSessionStorage(String key) {
    return (String) js.executeScript(String.format(
            "return sessionStorage.getItem('%s');", key));
}
```