# How can I get local storage data from chrome using selenium for java?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, google-chrome, local-storage

I have a chrome extension that stores local data with a manifest of

```
{
    "name": "Tab Listener",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "permissions": ["storage"],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["content.js"]
    }
}
```

and a content.js of

```
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function(activeInfo) {
    chrome.storage.local.set({currentTabIndex: 'testValue'}, function() {
    });

    chrome.storage.local.get('currentTabIndex', function(result) {
    alert('Value currently is ' + result.currentTabIndex);
    });
});
```

To the best of my knowledge this stores the variable fine, and the alert is displayed. Then, I try to get this variable in a java application using

```
WebStorage webStorage = (WebStorage) new Augmenter().augment(driver);
LocalStorage localStorage = webStorage.getLocalStorage();
SessionStorage sessionStorage = webStorage.getSessionStorage();
System.out.println(localStorage.getItem("currentTabIndex"));
System.out.println(sessionStorage.getItem("currentTabIndex"));
```

and both cases return null. I do launch my driver with chrome settings

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("user-data-dir=C:\\AutoSig\\personal\\chrome");
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

and confirmed that this indeed does store the data for chrome and carries over session to session. I'm relatively new to chrome add ons, and not sure what I'm doing wrong. Additonally, I have tried using the utility classes suggested in [This StackOverflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27565416/test-sessionstorage-with-selenium-webdriver) and have had no luck. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Make sure you switch the driver to the tab... "onActivated Fires when the active tab in a window changes"

Comment: I'm not quite following what you mean.

Comment: content.js sets and gets local storage when the tab is activated.  Selenium has a command to switch tabs: driver.switchTo()

Comment: right, my overall goal is to have Selenium know that the active tab is, after being changed in the browser. My idea was to build an extension that could store the data, and then load it in my Java application.

Comment: This would only be useful if you were trying to determine a human's active tab.  (This script only fires when a human clicks on a tab.) Selenium always knows its own active tab.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to set Selenium's active tab to the humans active tab after they change it directly in the browser. Which after a lot of research I have realized is no small task.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String getItemFromLocalStorage(String key)
{
        JavascriptExecutor js = ((JavascriptExecutor)ios_mob_driver);
        return (String) js.executeScript(String.format("return window.localStorage.getItem('%s');", key));
}
```

I used and working fine for me .